# Как хранятся типы в object[] ?

Tags: c#

Есть код

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        object[] objects = new object[] {1, "asd", 'a'};
        foreach (var elem in objects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(elem.GetType().ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Выводятся типы System.Int, System.String, System.Char.
Вопрос - откуда компилятор знает о типах если явного приведения нет, обратиться из кода к методам объектов нельзя (кроме обжектовских). Мне казалось, что должны вывести System.Object, однако выводит правильно.

Comment: Рефлекшен, детка :-) И в данном случае не компилятор.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Смотрите.

В .NET (как и в любом объектно-ориентированном языке) переменная-ссылка базового типа может указывать на объект производного типа. Вспомним, что в .NET `object` является предком всех типов. Это значит, что переменная может содержать фактически любой тип. Итак, у нас есть различие между compile-time-типом (тип ссылки) и runtime-типом (фактическим типом объекта, на который эта ссылка ссылается).

Теперь, [`GetType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx), согласно документации, возвращает именно runtime-тип, то есть настоящий тип объекта по ссылке.

Каким именно образом это реализовано, для программиста не должно быть важно. На самом деле, каждый объект в .NET неявно хранит указатель на таблицу с метаданными, в которых описан его тип — но это деталь конкретной реализации, на которую опираться не стоит.

Comment: Т.е. по сути привидение в коде нужно только для того, чтобы соблюдалась безопасность типов, в compile-time. В runtime все равно тип известен.

Comment: Так и есть. По сути в compile-time известен лишь декларируемый тип, приведение — явная операция, которая либо приводит к другому типу, либо бросает `InvalidCastException`, если runtime-тип не приводится к нужному типу.