# Почему GetType() возвращает тип наследника после апкаста?

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при таком коде
метод GetType() определяет тип экземпляра как Derived, если он был приведен к базовому?

```
    class Base {}
    class Derived : Base { }

     static void Main() 
        {
            Base baseClass = new Derived() as Base;
            Console.WriteLine(baseClass.GetType());
        }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как хранятся типы в object\[\] ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/259504/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%8b-%d0%b2-object)

Comment: или даже вот этот дубликат лучше: [Приведение типов С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507241/186999)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `baseClass` ссылается на `Derived`, хоть тип переменной и `Base`.

`as Base` - не нужно (оно ничего не делает), так как наследник и так *assignable* переменной родительского типа.

```
 static void Main() 
 {
   object o1 = new Base();
   object o2 = new Derived();
   Console.WriteLine(o1.GetType()); // Base
   Console.WriteLine(o2.GetType()); // Derived
 }
```

Comment: Все равно не понимаю. При строчке Base baseClass = new Derived() было бы логично, что экземпляр ссылается на Derived, хоть тип переменной и Base. Но в моем же примере мы экземпляр кастим к базовому

Comment: Спасибо большое, более менее понял. Нужно ещё почитать про касты внимательнее.